# Identify documents in mongodb when matching two key:value pairs within a single array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying to identify documents where both key-value pairs within an array match using the `aggregate` pipeline.  Specifically, if I want to find documents where one array contains `user_attribute.Name = Quests_In_Progress` and `user_attribute.Value =3`.  Below is an example of such a document that I'm trying to match.

If I use

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    "user_attribute.Name": "Quests_In_Progress",
    "user_attribute.Value": "3"
    }
})
```

It will match every document that contains `Quests_In_Progress` for user_attribute.Name in one element of the array and contains "3" for user_attribute.Value, regardless of whether they exist in the same element of the array or not.
i.e.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    "user_attribute.Name": "Quests_In_Progress",
    "user_attribute.Value": "0"
    }
})
```

will match the same document simply because one element of the array has a key:Value pair of `Value:0` and another element of the array contains a key:value pair of `Quests_In_Progress`.

What I want to do is identify documents where both of those conditions are met within one element of the array.

I tried to do this with `$elemMatch`, but I couldn't get it to work.  Plus the aggregate documentation doesn't indicate that `$elemMatch` works, so maybe that's why I couldn't get it to work.

Lastly, I need to use the aggregate pipeline, because there are a bunch of other things I have to do after finding these documents- specifically unwinding them.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5555bb32de938ce667f78ce00"),
    "user_attribute": [{
    "Value": "Facebook",
    "Name": "Social_Connection"
    }, {
    "Name": "Total_Fireteam_Missions_Initiated",
    "Value": "0"
    }, {
    "Name": "Quests_Completed",
    "Value": "3"
    }, {
    "Name": "Item_Slots_Owned",
    "Value": "36"
    }, {
    "Name": "Quests_In_Progress",
    "Value": "3"
    }, {
    "Name": "Player_Progression",
    "Value": "0"
    }, {
    "Value": "1",
    "Name": "Characters_Owned"
    }, {
    "Name": "Quests_Started",
    "Value": "6"
    }, {
    "Name": "Total_Friends",
    "Value": "0"
    }, {
    "Name": "Device_Type",
    "Value": "Phone"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks 011001000110000101110110011010, I appreciate it. I'm a stack overflow noob, but I'd like to give you some kind of reputation points.  I'll gladly do it if you can tell me how :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using $elemMatch

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{$match: {"user_attribute": {$elemMatch: {"Name":"Quests_In_Progress", "Value":"0"}}}}, { $out, "temp"}])
```

That query will find anyone who has element of their array "Quests_In_Progress" with a value of 0 and put it into the collection temp